# Advice on a GPU for Dell Precision T3500 for image processing

Tags: opencv, opencl, gpgpu

I am a grad student and in our lab, we have a Dell Precision T3500 (http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/precision-t3500/pd). We use it primarily for image processing research and we need to use OpenCV 2.4.7's "ocl" i.e., OpenCL bindings for parallelizing up our work for some publications.

I looked at the workstation's specs and it specifies that we can get a NVIDIA Quadro 5000 or an AMD FirePro V7900 (the best of both manufacturers for this workstation).

This is where I am confused. Most of the reviews compare performance for CAD/CAM, MAYA and other software. But we will be writing our own code using OpenCV. Can anyone help me out in choosing the best of these two GPUs? Or is there anyway I can get a better GPU by upgrading the power supply?

We would greatly appreciate all the advice we can get at this stage!

Thank you very much.

Comment: I would go for AMD if you are using OpenCL. Since it will give more power for the same price.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to look up some AMD cards now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using OpenCL I agree with DarkZeros. You probably should buy AMD HW. Nvidia supports OpenCL only grudgingly as they want everyone to use CUDA.

Both of the cards you showed seem to be rather similar. Theoretical maximum at around 1TFlops. However both of them are rather old and very expensive. If you are not bound by any purchasing agreement I really recommend you buy a consumer card. The specs in dell.com only mean that if you purchase the computer from them you can select a GPU for it. It does not limit what you can do afterwards.

Depending on the chassis you could change your power supply. That would mean you could purchase something like this [http://www.amazon.com/XFX-RADEON-1000MHz-Graphics-R9290XENFC/dp/B00G2OTRMA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00G2OTRMA) . It has double the memory of either of those professional cards and over 5x the theoretical processing power.

To be fair if you have the money to spend GTX Titan is still an excellent choice. It is about as fast as that AMD card and you can use CUDA with it if you need, considering how common CUDA is in scientific computing it might be wise to go with that.

However if you cannot switch your power supply, if it's non standard size or whatnot, then you are more limited. In that case you should search for pretty much the heftiest card that can run on 150W. Even those have perhaps double the performance of the cards the computer was originally available with.

Comment: Thank you for thoughts sharpneli. I will call the Dell tech support to ask them about the power supply upgrade. So here's my doubt: the spec specifies that the T3500 has "2xPCI Express(x16) Gen2 Graphics slots up to 150 watts". So how does adding a new, more powerful power supply change the wattage that the slots can handle?

Comment: The slots themselves don't supply more than 75W each as per PCI E spec. Additional power is supplied by an extra power cable(s) from the power supply. Search for "pcie auxiliary power cable" for more details. You can check your power source, it might already have some. However it is doubtful it could supply the massive 300W as required by the latest and greatest cards, but you might be able to put something that requires 200W there.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info! This really gives me a lot of GPUs to choose from.